# PLSQL text file creating line ending format

Tags: oracle, file, text, plsql, line

I've created a text file in some directory with "UTL_FILE.fOpen" method. Actually text file has been created. File line endings is Unix/LF format. But i want create with Windows CR/LF line ending type.

can you give me an any idea?

```
f := UTL_FILE.fOpen('UTL_FILE_DIR', pFileName, 'w', pLineSize);
pLine := pLine || pColValue;
DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(pCur);
UTL_FILE.fclose(f);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my solution here http://knoworacle.blogspot.com/2012/06/oracle-utlfile-with-examples.html and put the chars(chr(13) || chr(10)) at line ends.